# Getting "Permission Denied while getting drive credential error" in big query to tableau connection

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery, connection, tableau-api

I am having table in big query console which is getting populated by google sheets, While I try to access that table in tableau desktop I am getting "Permission Denied while getting drive credential error"

I need to access the data in tableau for analysis

I tried following methods :

1. Created temporary view table in big query and tried to access that view in tableau but not succeeded
2. Changing service accounts roles to big query data viewer

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons for this problem is that the Bigquery is synchronized with the table so Tableu is having a problem with authentication. Here is one of the resolution to this problem.

> The workaround is to schedule the query to run and store the (daily) data in a BigQuery view, then connect Tableau to that new source. As the query is being run by BigQuery, Tableau doesn't need to try to access your drive.

You can learn more about this error using this documentation created in Tableu: https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/error-code-015cfbe6-access-denied-bigquery-bigquery-permission-denied-while-getting-drive-credentials